# Draw special shapes right triangle with border radius in CSS3

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a way to draw a special shape like in the picture using Css3. Any idea or drawing way to draw that shape using Css3?

[image]

I have referenced several ways but it just draws into a normal triangle.

```css
#shape {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 72px solid transparent;
  border-right: 0px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 72px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="shape"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add `border-bottom-right-radius` in your `#shape` css. you just need to set the `border-left` to white or depending on your background color of your div to match the color

```css
#shape {
    width: 0;
    border-left: 72px solid white;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 72px solid red;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="shape"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the simplest and most sensible way I found ....

Answer (score 0):

it can be done using an after element on shape

```css
#shape{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;
    border-top: 0px solid transparent;
    border-right: 1px solid blue;
    border-bottom:1px solid blue;    
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#shape::after{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 1px;
  height: 150%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="shape"></div>
```